# Batch Script with checking option

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im trying to make this batch script check on resumption that it has not processed if a file before and continue with the ones it hasnt. i.e if it has processed a file, skip to the next one. What would I need to make this do such. thanks

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set EXE_FILE=E:\opencv\build\bin\Release\blobtrack_sample.exe
set INPUT_PATH=E:\Glasgow\Test\
set TRACKS_PATH=E:\Glasgow\Tracks\
set COUNT=0
pushd %INPUT_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
  set /a COUNT+=1
  echo Processing %%f, track=%%~nf.txt, btavi=test!COUNT!%%~xf
  %EXE_FILE% fg=FG_0S bd=BD_CC bt=CCMSPF btpp=None bta=Kalman btgen=RawTracks track=%TRACKS_PATH%\%%~nf.txt FGTrainFrames=125 %%f
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether `%OUTPUT_PATH%\%%~nf.avi` exists:

```
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 if not exists "%OUTPUT_PATH%\%%~nf.avi" (
  set /a COUNT+=1
  echo Processing %%f, track=%%~nf.txt, btavi=test!COUNT!%%~xf
  %EXE_FILE% fg=FG_0S bd=BD_CC bt=CCMSPF btpp=None bta=Kalman btgen=RawTracks track=%TRACKS_PATH%\%%~nf.txt FGTrainFrames=125 btavi=%OUTPUT_PATH%\%%~nf.avi %%f
)
```

But that has a slight problem. If processing breaks for some reasin in the middle of a written file you have half a file that doesn't get processed again, because you equate *existence* with *completion*.

A more robust way would be to write to a temporary file first and then rename it:

```
%EXE_FILE% fg=FG_0S bd=BD_CC bt=CCMSPF btpp=None bta=Kalman btgen=RawTracks track=%TRACKS_PATH%\%%~nf.txt FGTrainFrames=125 btavi=%OUTPUT_PATH%\temp.avi %%f
ren "%OUTPUT_PATH%\temp.avi" "%%~nf.avi"
```

Comment: If you pick a temporary file name that won't conflict with your output file names it should be all good. A temporary folder has the problem that a simple rename doesn't suffice and the move might span different volumes (I don't know how your folders are set up there). But yes, you can. I was just giving a suggestion, you're not forced to use the code exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: Yes, the rename should be inside the loop.

Comment: Where do you get it and why? I'm not a psychic.

Comment: Trying the `MOVE` command instead renames the files, but the `REN` command doesnt.

Comment: That depends on how the process communicates an abort due to an error. If the exit code of the process is non-zero you could just chain the rename with `&&`, i.e. `foo -blah ... && move ...`. In that case the rename will only be executed if `foo` executes without error.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if your output file already exists

```
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
  if not exist "%OUTPUT_PATH%\%%~nf.avi" (
    set /a COUNT+=1
    echo Processing %%f, track=%%~nf.txt, btavi=test!COUNT!%%~xf
    %EXE_FILE% fg=FG_0S bd=BD_CC bt=CCMSPF btpp=None bta=Kalman btgen=RawTracks track=%TRACKS_PATH%\%%~nf.txt FGTrainFrames=125 btavi=%OUTPUT_PATH%\%%~nf.avi %%f
  )
)
```

It seems to me it might be more efficient if your IN (*) clause were restricted to look for a specific extension.

Comment: You can use `for %%f in (*.foo)` to select only `.foo` files. That way you don't have to check whether you accidentally grabbed the batch file and tried to process it.